# CollectionFS Graphicsmagick resize width only if larger than

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, collectionfs

On collectionfs I have following method to resize large images to width of 1200px and height remains proportional in order to reduce file size.

```
var createPic = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize(1200).quality(100).autoOrient().stream().pipe(writeStream);
}
```

Images with lets say 2000x2000 dimension actually end up uploaded 1200x1200 but larger in file size. Can you explain why? And how can I modify the method to only resize image if width exceeds for example 2000px?

Comment: Also, does anyone know how much facebook reduces photos in size and quality? Or do they use some kind of algorithm depending on image?

Comment: Just a guess, but try `resize("1200x1200>")` in there.

Comment: That didn't resize at all and more than doubled the image file size. original image is 1919x1919 1.3mb. I had 1200x1200 1.8mb. With your guess it is 1919x1919 2.9mb

Comment: Maybe `resize('1200','1200>')`

Comment: 1200x1200 1.8mb. Can you explain the second argument. I assume this is the height.

Comment: The first is likely to be the width, the second being the height. It may accept a `>` tacked on the end of the height to mean it should only resize images larger than the given number, and a `<` to mean it should ony upsize smaller ones and a `!` to ignore aspect ratio. These additional *flags* may possibly be accepted as a third parameter in single quotes. I don"t know - I am guessing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22135437/5376225 here explains increase in filesize. But I'm not sure. Thanks for help.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your images!

Comment: You could try removing the `quality` parameter, or more likely, reducing the colours to 31 or 63 or 254... AFTER resizing.

Comment: Yeah I actually removed quality parameter images are in kbs now but thats ok for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize(1200, 1200, '>').quality(100).autoOrient().stream().pipe(writeStream);
```

However, after using it with the gridfs package you may get this error:
`Error: <ID> does not exist`. This is a package's bug, so this topic would go separately.

Comment: fs packages are deprecated, the announcement is [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/deprecating-collectionfs/16921)